# are bootstrap grid breakpoints usually just enough, or is it more common to make other breakpoints?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-grid

The grid system as I understand

- xs = 0-767 pixels
- sm = 768-991 pixels
- md = 992-1199 pixels
- lg = 1200 pixels and up

so, don't you guys feel like the xs class is completely not small and definitely not extra.
I'm thinking of making a tiny breakpoint, and want to know is it common to do this or is there something I'm not getting right!!
and what is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: It would be nice to get an answer from the questioner or a answer marked as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a media query in your custom css file for a max screen size of 400 pixels for this. I do that quite often. Especially for old iPhones, which render HTML at a width of 350 pixels.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See Bootstrap 4: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

They change the breakpoints to

- Extra small: <576px
- Small: ≥576px
- Medium: ≥768px
- Large: ≥992px
- Extra large: ≥1200px

So I think the XS breakpoint was to wide.